# Any one tell text based sms using SMSManager in android

Tags: java, android

This is my code using

```
    SendSMS sendSMS = new SendSMS();
sendSMS.sendSMS("mobileNumber", "message", context); 
public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message,final Context context)
    {        
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        //---when the SMS has been sent---
       context. registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "SMS sent", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Generic failure", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "No service", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Null PDU", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Radio off", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        //---when the SMS has been delivered---
       context. registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "SMS delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "SMS not delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;                        
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);        
    }
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Generic failure problem occured in mobile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lot of codes available on net. one of theme here: [How to Send large Sms in Android](http://www.coders-hub.com/2013/09/how-to-send-sms-in-android-without-any.html)

Comment: than up vote and mark as answer Sir.